# Can an ace be used at the bottom of a hand besides 5,4,3,2,A?

Tags: rules

I have been told that an ace can be used at the bottom of a strait even if the lowest card is not a 2. Is this true? For example: 9,8,7,6,A...is this an actual poker hand?

Comment: Really an ace is like a semi joker?  I think a range of questions is good for this site but that is outside my range.  -1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just silly

Comment: It's straight, and where did you hear that? -1 for lack of effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is one extremely simple Google search away.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I am going to vote to reopen because the use of the Ace for straights is not intuitive or logical to new players, and also not duplicate to hand reading questions.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Here are some other questions that are easily answered by a simple Google Search: http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/what-tie-breakers-exist/4400 , http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-are-side-pots-built, http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/in-live-play-why-do-poker-players-wait-their-turn-before-looking-at-their-cards, http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/573/why-does-555-beat-qqq-in-this-doyle-vs-elezra-hand/574 ; all of which you either answered or asked. I'm also voting to reopen this, as it seems completely on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

That's a *hand* but not a straight. That's an ace high. An ace can be used at the bottom end of a wheel (slang for a five high straight), A-2-3-4-5 or at the top end of an ace high straight such as 10-J-Q-K-A. It cannot be used to fill in any other straights with conventional poker hands.